# IN statment on a MySQL INNER JOIN php pdo

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

i have an array i want to implode, then pass to a query and spit out all the matching values, but all i get is a `1064 violation`, im sure its some silly syntax i've missed.

```
$filmImplode = implode("','", $filmList);
$query = "
    SELECT
        watch.film_id,
        films.film_api_id
    FROM
        watch
        INNER JOIN films ON films.film_id = watch.film_id
    WHERE
        films.film_api_id IN ('$filmImplode')
        AND watch.user_id = :user_id";
$query_params = array(':user_id' => 1);
try {
    $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
    $getWatched = $stmt->execute($query_params);
} catch (PDOException $ex) {
    echo 'something went wrong' . $ex->getMessage();
}
$getWatched = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

The SQL error reads

something went wrongSQLSTATE[42000]:

> Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL
>   syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version
>   for the right syntax to use near
>   'item0','item1','item2','itme3','item4' at line 3

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because This topic has been answered in  [**info**](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/pdo/info) on PDO tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see 2 potential issues:

- you may have film names with quote that will mess up your query. Escape them.
- you have a space in your `: user_id` parameter

Try this:

```
array_walk($filmList, function(&$film){
    $film = $db->quote($film);
});
$filmImplode = implode(",", $filmList);
$query = "
    SELECT
        watch.film_id,
        films.film_api_id
    FROM
        watch
        INNER JOIN films ON films.film_id = watch.film_id
    WHERE
        films.film_api_id IN ($filmImplode)
        AND watch.user_id = :user_id";
$query_params = array(':user_id' => 1);
try {
    $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
    $getWatched = $stmt->execute($query_params);
} catch (PDOException $ex) {
    echo 'something went wrong' . $ex->getMessage();
}
$getWatched = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

An even better approach, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/920353/can-i-bind-an-array-to-an-in-condition), would be to build dynamically the `IN` condition writing the placeholders and to then bind the parameters in the `prepare` method.

Comment: so array walk, seems to destroy everything. not getting any output or errors. And the space i corrected, but still no joy

Answer (score -2):

The problem seems to be around filmImplode.
Are your film_api_ids int? If not, you should make sure they are passed as string constants in your SQL.

```
WHERE films.film_api_id IN ('XXX-123-XX', 'YYY-456-YY')
```

Instead of

```
WHERE films.film_api_id IN (XXX-123-XX, YYY-456-YY)
```

Also, those single quotes look shady, try without single quotes if all filmIds are integer.

```
WHERE films.film_api_id IN ($filmImplode)
```

Comment: Yep they are strings, and yea the output is showing they are correctly marked. ill edit and show error